# mongoose populate and return a document with path as a list

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I am using mongoose 5.9.28 and node v12.16.1.

I need to write a function which takes a list as param and populate that list in mongoose model. (Model is Constant in function)

My Schema:

```
    var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    id : {
        type : String,
        required : true,
        unique : true,
    },
    driverId : {
        type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref : "drivers"            
    },
    vehicleId : {
        type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref : "vehicles"            
    },
    customerId : {
        type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref : "customers",
        required : true            
    },
    bookedOn : {
        type : String
    },
    pickUpLocation : {
        type : String,
        required : true,
    },
    dropLocation : {
        type : String,
        required : true
    },
    paymentId : {
        type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref : "payments"             
    },
    bookingStatusId :{
        type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref : "booking_status"             
    },  
    goodsType : {
        type : String,
        required : true
    }     
});
```

Here driverId, vehicleId, customerId, paymentId, bookingStatusId are references to other models.

I have this function where refs is a list.

```
const getBookings = async (refs) => {
    const booking = await bookingModel.find().lean().populate({
                                     path : refs,
                                     select : ['-_id']
                                     ).exec()
    return booking;
}
```

If I call `getBookings(['customerId','driverId'])`, I should get the document with populated customer and driver details excluding the _id's.

But I get the error as `TypeError: utils.populate: invalid path. Expected string. Got typeof "object"`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose `Model#populate` accepts a single `path`. To populate multiple fields, you would need to use chaining as mentioned [here in the docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate_an_existing_mongoose_document).

You can run a loop on the `refs` array to chain populate the model. Something like:

```js
const getBookings = async (refs) => {
    let query = bookingModel.find().lean();
    refs.forEach((ref => query = query.populate({path: ref, select: ['-_id'] });
    const booking = await query.exec()
    return booking;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The mongoose populate method does only accept a String, which is the name of the field you want to refer to. So you can´t pass a list containing all field names you want to populate. You need to pass each name of the field you want to populate in a separate method call. Take a look into the following code snippet:

```
const booking = await bookingModel.find()
                           .lean()
                           .populate({ path: 'customerId', select: ['_id']})
                           .populate({ path: 'driverId', select: ['_id']})
                           .exec();
```

See also in the documentation: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populating-multiple-paths